# Is there an issue with System.Net.WebSockets, or do I just not understand websockets?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, websocket

I am trying to write a program which uses System.Net.WebSockets in .Net 8, but I am not seeing the results I am expecting. Here is a simplified example which doesn't work:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WebSocketController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task Get()
    {
        if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            using var webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
            await ReceiveMessages(webSocket);
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
        }
    }

    private static async Task ReceiveMessages(WebSocket webSocket)
    {
        WebSocketReceiveResult receiveResult;
        var buffer = new byte[1];
        do
        {
            receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
        } while (!receiveResult.CloseStatus.HasValue);

        await webSocket.CloseAsync(
            receiveResult.CloseStatus.Value,
            receiveResult.CloseStatusDescription,
            CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

The first message sent by the client will be received successfully, then `ReceiveAsync` will not return again consistently with any further messages sent from the client.

If I do add another line where I send a message back to the client after each message I receive, the program will have no issues receiving every message the client sends:

```
private static async Task ReceiveMessages(WebSocket webSocket)
{
    WebSocketReceiveResult receiveResult;
    var buffer = new byte[1];
    do
    {
        receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
        await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
    } while (!receiveResult.CloseStatus.HasValue);

    await webSocket.CloseAsync(
        receiveResult.CloseStatus.Value,
        receiveResult.CloseStatusDescription,
        CancellationToken.None);
}
```

In my use case, I don't need to send a message back to the client every time I receive a message. After reviewing the [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455) and [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocket?view=net-8.0) it seems like the top code block should work as is. Am I misunderstanding something about websockets or System.Net.WebSockets, or is this a bug with System.Net.WebSockets?

Edit: here is my Program.cs for what it is worth. It's just the default ASP.NET Core Web API template with one addition to use the WebSocketMiddleware.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.

        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseWebSockets();

        app.MapControllers();

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using your code it works well and no need to use AutoResetEvent, If the issue still happens, we might need to check the middlewares you are using.

Comment: If you could provide the sample, we could help you.

Comment: I updated my post with my program.cs. It's just the default ASP.NET Core Web API template with one addition to use the WebSocketMiddleware @JasonPan

Comment: Have you double checked your client end - is it definitely sending multiple messages, or is it waiting for a response before sending the next one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just confirmed the issue was on the client end - there seems to be an issue with Postman Websocket in this use case. I used my own client and this functions as expected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I recently had the same problem. Correct me if I'm wrong, but in my case, the WebSocket connection was terminated as soon as the Get request was completed.

To solve this, I used the **AutoResetEvent**, even though there might be a better solution. For my project, however, it was the best solution so far.

In your code, the implementation would look something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task Get()
{
    if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
    {
        var stopHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        using var webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
        await ReceiveMessages(webSocket, stopHandle);
        
        stopHandle.WaitOne();
    }
    else
    {
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
    }
}
```

This stopHandle is now there to wait at this point until it is told to continue.

This is exactly what you tell it when you close the connection.

```
    private static async Task ReceiveMessages(WebSocket webSocket, AutoResetEvent stopHandle)
    {
        WebSocketReceiveResult receiveResult;
        var buffer = new byte[1];
        do
        {
            receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
            await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
        } while (!receiveResult.CloseStatus.HasValue);

        await webSocket.CloseAsync(
            receiveResult.CloseStatus.Value,
            receiveResult.CloseStatusDescription,
            CancellationToken.None);
        stopHandle.Set(); // Tell the stopHandle not to wait any longer
    }
```

As I said. It may be relatively unattractive, but it works.

Btw. dont forget to add the "UseWebSockets" Middleware to the request-pipeline.

```
app.UseWebSockets();
```

Comment: The op's code is correct and there is no need to use `AutoResetEvent`. Everything runs fine in my test environment.

Comment: If you think your answer is a solution, please explain why you added `await webSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);`, the running result will be difference.

Comment: I am using the WebSocketMiddleware, and I am also having no issues with the websocket connection being terminated. It stays open, but `websocket.ReceiveAsync` is not returning with messages consistently.